# Reordering MutableArray Based on What Appears in Table

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array (**NSMutableArray**) of dictionary (**NSMutableDictionary**) that stores images and some strings.

```
@interface SelectViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *pictureArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1;
    UIImage *key1; // UIImage
    NSString *key2; // file name
    NSString *key3; // file path
    NSString *key4; // description
    NSString *key5; // order    
}
```

I want to let the user reorder rows.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIImage *image = [[pictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key1];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    NSString *filename = [[pictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:key2];
    cell.textLabel.text = filename;
    cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"From %i to %i",fromIndexPath.row,toIndexPath.row);
}
```

So a gray symbol appears on each table row, and the user can reorder rows.  My question is how can I reorder the array (pictureArray) based on what appears on the table?  I segue-pass this array to another class.  The order of appearance of the array hasn't changed yet.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)targetIndexPath
{
    NSUInteger sourceIndex = [sourceIndexPath row];
    NSUInteger targetIndex = [targetIndexPath row];
    if (sourceIndex != targetIndex)
    {
        NSString *item = [pictureArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndex];
        [pictureArray removeObject:item];
        [pictureArray insertObject:item atIndex:targetIndex];
    }
}
```

**Just place this**

Comment: Oh, my gosh...  It's that simple!?  Thanks a lot.  I'll check-accept the answer in 3 minutes.  I'm glad you understand what I need.

Comment: @Manohar +1 Can you do the same with this code [pictureArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndex withObjectAtIndex:targetIndex]; If you can it would be more elegant

Comment: Anupdas, it seems that your code will break the order of appearance a bit.  Possibly, one of the rows that is supposed to be removed is not removed.